# Spring boot, transaction is not rollback after test

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am writing unit tests for my service. The problem is that, after test is finished, transactions are not rollback automatically by spring boot.

Here is my tests:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = { TestApplicationConfiguration.class, TestDataSourceConfiguration.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class BoardServiceTest {

@Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private CardService cardService;

    @Autowired
    private BoardCardService boardCardService;

    @Autowired
    private BoardService boardService;

    @Autowired
    private CommonBoardService commonBoardService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthorityService authorityService;

    @Test(expected = CommonException.class)
    @Transactional
    public void testCreateBoardStatusAFK() {
        final User admin = userService.findUserById(1l);
        admin.setCurrentBoard(null);

        Board board = boardService.startBoard(admin);
        assertEquals(board, admin.getCurrentBoard());

        // Board has status IN_PROGRESS, current time < timeToComplete
        board.setSelectedCardsCount(boardService.getDefaultCardsToSelectCount() - 1);
        board.setTimeToComplete(DateUtils.addHours(new Date(), boardService.getDefaultMinsToComplete()));
        board = commonBoardService.save(board);
        board = boardService.startBoard(admin);
        assertEquals(admin.getCurrentBoard().getStatus(), Board.IN_PROGRESS);

        // Board has status IN_PROGRESS, current time > timeToComplete
        board.setTimeToComplete(DateUtils.addHours(new Date(), -1));
        board = commonBoardService.save(board);
        board = boardService.startBoard(admin);

        assertEquals(admin.getCurrentBoard().getStatus(), Board.AFK);
    }
}
```

After test execution, the corresponding table in test db is populated by new record.

Please, tell me, how solve this issue?

**Update:**

Here is the implementation of my service method, that is invoked during test:

```
   @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Board update(Board board, Date finishedDate, Integer status) {
        board.setStatus(status);
        board.setFinishedDate(finishedDate);

        return boardRepository.save(board);
    }
```

As, you can see, new transaction is opened when this method is called.
In my debugging console, I see the following info, after update is complete:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('boards_id_seq')
Hibernate: insert into boards (created_date, updated_date, cards_to_hold, cards_to_select, finished_date, holded_cards_count, selected_cards_count, started_date, status, time_to_complete, time_to_next_board, user_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I don't understand, why hibernate create new entity in db, although I am updating existing one.
So, maybe this is the reason of such behaviour?

Comment: If you're writing a unit test, wouldn't it make it easier if you mocked the classes that store stuff inside the database? (Like a repository, entitymanager, ...)

Comment: @g00glen00b, Well, as the spring manages the transactions in tests, therefore I don't want to mock other components.

Comment: Regards to rolling back in the test. You can annotate you test class with **@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)**. This will make the transaction always to rollback. Also annotate the test class with **@Transactional** to ensure that all tests will rollback

Comment: @DanielDiehl, hi, **@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)** is deprecated. Are there other one to use?

Comment: Spring 4 provides and recommends the new `@Rollback` annotation on test classes/methods.

Comment: @i-domshchikov, since spring 4.2 you can anotate your class as **@Rollback(true)** and **@Transactional**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a rollbackFor paramter in your transactional annotation. `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)` Default rollback works only for unchecked exceptions(instance of RuntimeException or Error) with Transactional annotation